# If multiple people roll a die, what's the probability to roll the highest number?

Tags: probability

> If multiple people roll a die, whats the chance of rolling the highest number?

**SOURCE:** Specifically this question comes from a computer game where $5$ or $20$ people roll a $100$ sided die to see which person may receive a reward.

We were wondering if the probability is higher than $1$ over the number of people rolling the die.

Comment: What happens it there's a tie?

Comment: Since the setup is symmetric, its just 1/number of people (assuming ties=rerolls)

Comment: Those people roll again.